# Webpack cannot resolve module error

Tags: webpack, vue.js

So I am trying to compile a `vue` file.
But I am getting the following error[image]

and I don't know why. My `main.js` file contains the following

```
// Vue things
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource)


// Vue Components
import dashboard from 'components/dashboard-component'

new Vue({
    el: "body",
    components: {
        dashboard
    },
    methods: {
    }
})
```

and my components folder is in the same folder as `main.js`.
This is my vue component:

```
<template>
Hello
</template>

<script>
// Exports
export default {
    components: {
        dashboard
    },
    props: {
    },
    data: function (argument) {
    },
    ready() {
    },
    methods: {
    }
}
</script>
```

which is under components/dashboard-component as `index.vue`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import Vue files. So you need to save your component to `components/Dashboard/Dashboard.vue` and import it like so:

```
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard/Dashboard.vue'

new Vue({
    el: "body",
    components: {
        Dashboard
    },
    methods: {
    }
})
```

Don't forget the `./` in front of the `components` folder in order for this to work

Comment: Now it says the following thing: `ERROR in ./view/vue/components/dashboard/dashboard.vue. Module build faild: TypeError: this._init is not a function` and I don't have a function called `_init` in `dashboard.vue`

Comment: Try to install the following dependencies: `npm install --save vue vue-loader vue-html-loader css-loader style-loader babel-loader babel-core babel-plugin-transform-runtime babel-preset-es2015 babel-runtime vue-hot-reload-api` this is an error reported in github issues: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/23

Answer (score 2):

For convinient, I would usual add `.vue` to resolved extensions Array, and set alias for directories that would be used frequently:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
  fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
  alias: {
    'data': path.resolve(__dirname, '../data'),
    'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
    'views': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/views'),
    'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
  }
},
```

So I can use `import dashboard from 'components/dashboard-component';` in my project.